# Best practise apache camel approach for doing data translation based on simple look ups

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm wondering if I'm missing a solution to a very common scenario/repeatable (EI)pattern, in Camel's amazing Swiss Army toolkit?

With System interoperability, you will need to translate message body data from System A for sending to System B based on a mapping/lookup.

For example a Dept Code of "ACC" in System A is required to be translated to 'DEC' in System B. And the data mapping could be a CSV or DB table with 2 columns of SystemADeptCodes and SystemBDeptCodes for easy lookup. I think this is sometimes called Cross reference (Xref) or Domain Value Mapping...?

Should this be done using an `ENRICH` Component - with a `SQL` or `CSV` component to read in the Lookup Table, and use an Aggregation Strategy?

Or should I use a `MESSAGE TRANSLATOR` with a bean that does the lookup and substitution in Java?

Or is there some other camel magic I'm missing.

Apologies if I'm sounding lazy but Camel has made my life so easy in other ways since discovery and I'm curious to see if I'm missing a trick.

Cheers